# How do I reboot a remote Linux server with a failed disk?

Tags: linux

I have a somewhat difficult problem. I have a remote server that I won't be nearby to reboot for a few days I'd like to get restarted. The problem is that the disk seems to have crashed and I can't just run the shutdown command since it's a binary on the disk.

I've found a cool method online here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/rebooting-magic-way however this command assumes I have root permissions, but my currently logged in account is just a regular user with sudo permissions. Running sudo just gives me an error since it can't read the sudoer's file to verify my permissions.

Any thoughts? I'm still logged in through SSH for now, but I don't expect it to let me back in if I log out.

Comment: Do you know the `root` password? If so, try just running `su` and using the root password to become root; this will require reading from `/etc/shadow` however..

Comment: I do know the root password, but like you mentioned, running su requires use of the filesystem unfortunately.

Comment: To be fair though... why do you want to issue a _reboot_ command against a machine with a failed disk that you won't be near for a few days? Seems like a good way of getting it stuck in a boot loop.

Comment: Well it's just an issue with the SD card because I was hammering it too hard. I've had this issue before and rebooting it kicked it back online just fine. Right now the server is as good as useless to me.

Comment: Someone else may have a better answer for you, but if you can not even elevate to the root answer I am afraid I have no solution - I am assuming your user does not even have the permissions required to attempt a remount of the disk?

Comment: It does not have the required permissions, however even if it did the /bin/mount is on disk as well so it's a moot point.

Comment: If you have access to the server, use and "abuse" installed software (mysql, etc) to get something be be run with root privileges. Look for any payload you can send to the server that allows you to escalate privileges, you are inside already, just hack it... if you need to write something, create a ramdisk/ramdrive...

Afterwards, running something like what is on that link and others (for instance: https://major.io/2009/01/29/linux-emergency-reboot-or-shutdown-with-magic-commands/) :

echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq 
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger

Would make a dirty reboot.

Comment: If you can write to `/tmp`, then you should be able use `echo` and `>>` to get stuff onto the remote machine. At least you would be able to fill up `/tmp` and possibly cause it to crash.